# Adding dynamic values to select for every row in Tabulator

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabulator

I have a list of items. Each item contains a list within it as well. I want to add that list in dropdown in tabulator. I am using tabulator v4.4.1.

Item 1:

```
{
  "attribute1": "Value1",
  "attribute2": "Value2",
  "list": [ "ListItem1", "ListItem2" ]
}
```

Item 2:

```
{
  "attribute1": "Value1",
  "attribute2": "Value2",
  "list": [ "ListItem1", "ListItem2", "ListItem3" ]
}
```

Each item has different `list`. I want to add ListItems in a dropdown in a cell in tabulator.

```
{
  title: "List", 
  field: "list", 
  editor: "select", 
  editorParams: function(cell) {
    var values = {};
    var list = cell.getData().list;
    list.forEach(function(item) {
      values[item] = item;
    });
    return {
      values: values
    };
  }
}
```

However this code does not attach values to dropdown. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Not sure but this  ```var list = cell.getData().list;``` can be shortened to ```var list = cell.getValue();```  Do see any errors in the console?  If you put a ```console.log(values)``` just before the ```return``` do you see the list items?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a simple array then you can significantly simplify your example as that can be passed directly into the values property.

```js
{
  title: "List", 
  field: "list", 
  editor: "select", 
  editorParams: function(cell) {
    return {
      values: cell.getData().list
    };
  }
}
```

Im assuming that there is an error in your example and that the list column should be separate from the column with the editor on. otherwise there would be no list to show because the value of the column would replace it

Comment: Thanks!! Will try it and let you know the actual solution I used.